# How to add new C++ header and source files in Qt Creator with CMake build?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I am currently looking for a way to add new C++ header and source file from the Qt creator GUI Application with CMake builder.

The issue is `CMakeLists.txt` file is not including those files.

This is the CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(MyTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

if(ANDROID)
  add_library(MyTest SHARED
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
  )
else()
  add_executable(MyTest
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
  )
endif()

target_link_libraries(MyTest PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
```

I will then go to Qt Creator and create a new C++ file. (This file will create separate **header(.h)** and **source(.cpp)** files. If the file name is `MyCustom`, then it will create `mycustom.h` & `mycustom.cpp` files.

Those files are not automatically added  into the `add_executable()` section of CMakeLists. I have to manually add them to `add_executable()` to include them. Is that the way Qt creator and CMakeLists work or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , As of version Qt Creator 4.10.2 . When you add new files it were not added to CMakeLists.txt by default. But you can make work around by using CMake `file` command.

1. Move your source and header files to a new subfolder ( sources )
2. Edit your CMakeLists.txt to include that.

example:

```cmake
file(GLOB SRCS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sources/*.cpp")
add_executable(MyTest ${SRCS})
```

Comment: I am using QT Creator 4.12.0 version. Is that version too not include newly created files in the CMakeLists.txt file ?

Comment: I don't have 4.12.0 installed. But i think it will be the same.

Comment: ok. I will try to add that change and let you know. thank you